# JQuery How to activate a button when clicked

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, marionette

I have pagination buttons like this:

```
<div style="float: right;" id="editable_paginate" class="dataTables_paginate paging_simple_numbers">
    <ul class="pagination">
        <li id="editable_previous" class="js_paginate_button previous disabled"><a href="#">Précédent</a></li>
        <li class="js_paginate_button active"><a href="#">1</a></li>
        <li class="js_paginate_button "><a href="#">2</a></li>
        <li class="js_paginate_button "><a href="#">3</a></li>
        <li class="js_paginate_button "><a href="#">4</a></li>
        <li class="js_paginate_button "><a href="#">5</a></li>
        <li id="editable_next" class="js_paginate_button next"><a href="#">Suivant</a></li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

By default, the first button has 'active' class. When I click the 2nd button, for example, I need to activate that button and de-activate the first button.
I have implemented the function below, but `$(this).addClass('active');` is not working.

```
View.PharmaciesView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    events : {
        "click li.js_paginate_button":"paginate"
    },
    paginate : function(e) {
        $('li.js_paginate_button').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        e.preventDefault(); 
    }
});
```

What is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0):

**this** in *paginate* method is instance of View.PharmaciesView.
To get button element use construction:

```
$(e.target).addClass('active');
```